# Replace specific character with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that takes user input for a filename:

```
set /p Name=Name:
```

However, if the file name has multiple words, I want the batch file to replace the spaces with dashes.

For example if the user types in "apple pie" I would want the batch file to change it to "apple-pie"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch files support substring replacement.

Here I replace the space with an underscore.

```
@echo off
set /p Name=File Name:
set Name=%Name: =_%
echo %Name%
```

Comment: More info [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) (a good site to learn about scripting in general).